# Can't get into Clockworkmod recovery on LG Optimus 2x

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode, lg-optimus-2x

I flashed a MoDaCo ROM this afternoon just to try it on my LG Optimus 2x P990, which was on ICS (CM9). I see that it's based on the offical LG Optimus 2x ROM, but I decided to flash it back to Android 4.0.4 ICS again, the one I was coming from.

But I can't get into ClockworkMod Recovery. I didn't find ROM Manager on my phone after flash (it works, except for Market and has **very** many bugs), so I reinstalled it by sending the *.apk to my email. I installed CWM successfully, but I can't get into it. I have tried the volume and power button method and reboot from ROM Manager. None of them worked.

My phone does works (call and such), but I can't get into CWM, which is **really** annoying.

Comment: A successful flash of CWM should boot you into CWM, so how do you know it was successful?

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by flashing ClockWorkMod and the boot image manually. Then, I used the volume down and power buttons to get into it. Now, I'm running Android 4.0.4 ICS again.